# R function to replace multiple values in a dataset

Tags: r, plyr

I am very new to R and coding in general. I am processing HT-qPCR data and have hundreds of gene codes that need to be changed to the gene names. I am using the function revalue from the package plyr and that is working perfectly:

```
Ct1 <- revalue(Ct_data$Gene, c("AY1" = "16s"))
```

However as I have hundreds of values to rename I was wondering is there a way to do this on a loop for all samples? I have an excel file with the gene codes with their corresponding gene names so could someone point me in the right direction of how to use this excel file to rename the values?

Comment: Hi. You do mean replace values, right? Renaming would be for column names.

Comment: Hi , yes I mean replace values

Answer (score 0):

If your replacements are already in a data frame (read your Excel file into R), then this is a join. Something like this:

```
# 1 read your excel file into R
library(readxl)
lookup = read_excel("path/to/your_excel.xlsx")
## I'll pretend the column names are `bad_name` and `good_name`

# 2 join to your current data
library(dplyr)
Ct_data = left_join(Ct_data, by = c("Gene" = "bad_name"))

# 3 OPTIONAL manually spot-check to make sure the good names are correct
View(Ct_data[c("Gene", "good_name")])

# 4 OPTIONAL if not all names are replaced, you may need to keep the original name in case `good_name` is missing
Ct_data = Ct_data %>% 
  mutate(good_name = coalesce(good_name, Gene))

# Drop the old column, keep the new
Ct_data = Ct_data %>% 
  select(-Gene) %>% 
  rename(Gen = good_name)
```

If you need more help, please post a small reproducible example with a few rows of data illustrating the remaining issues. `dput()` is the nicest way to share data because it is copy/pasteable and preserves all class and structure information, e.g. `dput(Ct_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. Choose a relevant subset to share.